# ion-auto-complete module throwing template parsing error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, autocomplete, ionic3

I am creating an app which requires auto-complete feature. I explored some modules and finally found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-auto-complete). I followed the exact steps mentioned in it. When I am running the project, it's throwing template parsing error.
Here are the error logs:

syntaxError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94602:34 TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:118465:19 JitCompiler.prototype._parseTemplate@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127893:16 JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127868:18 JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127770:56 JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127770:9 JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127640:13 then@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94591:77 JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127639:16 JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:127555:32 CompilerImpl.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:93438:34 PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModule@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:6110:16 [361]@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1143:1 **webpack_require**@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:12 webpackJsonpCallback@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23 @http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1

What can be the possible cause and solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this module to the specific component's module file.
Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete/issues/109) discussion.

Comment: Thanks @LalitKushwah